# how switch statement works with hex cases

Tags: c

I created a function to convert a hex reason to another hex reason.
The function always goes to default case.

```
static uint8_t convert_reason_code(uint32_t reason)
{
    printf("reason %u is ==== \n",reason);
    switch (reason) {

        case 0x02 :
           printf("reason A\n");
           return 0x01

        case 0x88 :
            printf("reason B\n");
            return  0x02;

        case 0x44 :
            printf("reason C\n");
            return 0x03 ;

        default:
            printf("default\n"); //always prints default
            return 0X00 ;
    }
}
```

If I explicitly change the reason code inside the function, then 
switch case works properly.

```
static uint8_t convert_reason_code(uint32_t reason)
{
    printf("reason %u is ==== \n",reason);
    reason = 0x44
    switch (reason) {
        case 0x44:
           printf("reason C\n"); //will be printed
    }
}
```

Is it because the reason is 32bit and cases are all 8bits? How should I label my cases so that 32bit reason works?

Comment: What does your debug message print?

Comment: _Hexadecimal integer literals_ can be used identical to _decimal integer literals_. What makes you think they have to be used different? (retorical question). You code will not compiler: `;` missing after `0x01`. You should, however, tag the literals as unsigned, like `0x01U`.

Comment: Please state exactly the problem and expected output. Try running that code in a debugger. (Note: the second version does also not compile!). To `printf()` `stdint.h` types use `inttypes.h` macros. Do not use the standard type specifiers.

Comment: Note that the _case labels_ are not 8 bits, but follow integer [promotion rules](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2p5).

Comment: Please show the code where you call this function.

Comment: If your default case is always executed, then it follows that the switch expression never takes the value of any of the enumerated cases.  The radix in which you express the case constants has nothing whatever to do with it.  Note also, by the way, that your debugging statement prints the a *decimal* representation of the value of your reason code, not a hexadecimal one.  Perhaps that is contributing to your confusion.

Comment: A number is not a notation: 9, `0b1011`, `0x9`, `011`, *IX* (roman numerals), `nine`, `neuf`  (French), 5+4 all *represent* the *same* number.

Comment: `return 0x01` forget `;`, can't compile. fixed then work [fine](http://ideone.com/XiMUqw)